# Find $c\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f$ such that $\int_c^xt\cdot f(t)\,\mathrm{d}x=x\sin (x)+\cos (x)+\frac{x^3}3$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

> Find a number and a function that satisfies:
> $$\displaystyle\int_{c}^{x}t\cdot f(t)\,\mathrm{d}x=x\sin (x)+\cos (x)+\dfrac{x^3}{3}$$

I tried taking derivative both sides so I got:

$$\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}t\cdot f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\displaystyle\int_{0}^{c}t \cdot f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^\prime=x \cos(x)+x^2 $$

It's clear that the right part of the integral will be $0$ because it's constant:

$$\left( \displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} t \cdot f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right)^{\prime}=x \cos(x)+x^2$$

But I didn't do rest. Because I don't know how to derive the integral with two functions. I know with one function like $\int_{0}^{x} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$. Thanks!

Comment: use the second fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: Can you remind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define:
$$g(t)=tf(t)$$
$$F(x)=\int_0^xg(t)\,dt$$
so we have:
$$F(x)-F(c)=x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\frac{x^3}3$$
now if we differentiate both sides it should be clear that:
$$g(x)=xf(x)=\left(x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\frac{x^3}3\right)'$$
now calculate the derivative and divide through by $x$:
$$xf(x)=\sin(x)+x\cos(x)-\sin(x)+x^2$$
$$f(x)=x+\cos(x)$$

---

Now if we sub back in:
$$\int_c^x\left[t^2+t\cos(t)\right]dt=x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\frac{x^3}{3}$$
$$x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{3c\sin(c)+3\cos(c)+c^3}{3}=x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\frac{x^3}3$$
and now you are left with:
$$3c\sin(c)+3\cos(c)+c^3=0$$
$$c\sin(c)+\cos(c)+\frac{c^3}{3}=0$$
and now there isn't an analytical way to solve this so a numerical method is the best you can do

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when involving two variables, you should clarify the variable which you are differentiating. Following from your question, because of the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have:
$$
\frac{d\left( \displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} t \cdot f(t)\mathrm{d}t \right)}{dx}=x \cos(x)+x^2
$$
Implies:
$$
xf(x)=x\cos(x)+x^2 \implies f(x)=\cos(x)+x
$$
Let's go back to the beginning. If we substitute the value of $f$, we get:
Implies:

$$
\left( \displaystyle\int_{c}^{x} t \cdot (\cos(t)+t)\mathrm{d}t \right)=x\sin (x)+\cos (x)+\dfrac{x^3}{3}
$$
After doing all the calculations, we will have:
$$
c\sin (c)+\cos (c)+\dfrac{c^3}{3}=0
$$
I used an external program to solve this, but you can use Bolzano's Theorem to see that the equation has a solution for some $c\in [-1,0]$

Comment: That is where I stuck, so without program we can't solve this isn't it?

Comment: Well, us mathematicians don't usually think about explicitly solving a problem, we are okay just knowing that such solution exists. There could be a way to solve the problem explicitly, but we have tools that allow us to know there is a solution (in fact, this solution is unique due to Rolle's Theorem)

Answer (score 3):

As said in answers, there is no way to find the zero of function $$f(c)=3c\sin(c)+3\cos(c)+c^3$$ but we can make nice approximations.

By inspection, the solution is "close" to $c=-\frac \pi 2$. So, we can do **one** single iteration of Householder method and obtain, *by hand*, the estimate
$$c \sim -\frac{1872 \pi +552 \pi ^3-5 \pi ^5}{1152+1104 \pi ^2+8 \pi ^4}$$ which is $-1.673493$ while the "exact" solution is $-1.673463$.

Answer (score 1):

You can still think of $t\mapsto tf(t)$ as a function, and differentiate as you normally would using the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus):
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_{0}^{x} t \cdot f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right) = xf(x).$$

Comment: I will try thanks!

Comment: It worked thanks!